# Export Eclipse plugin as directory on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, plugins

I am trying to export an Eclipse plugin as a directory on Mac. I do the normal procedure where I export as Directory but I don't use the option to package as jar under Options. This works on Linux, but not on Mac; I always get a jar file. Is there a reason why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still haven't found the answer but the workaround is very simple; just use jar command to extract the jar content which is the same as export-as-directory content.